# Sliderinput Shiny from own dataset

Tags: input, shiny, slider, dataset, rstudio

I'm currently working on a shiny app, but I've got some problems with a slider input. I've got 500.000 variables called 'duration' which all correspond a specific 'price'. However, the range of the duration is between 1-around 50000, so min - max isn't working properly. Therefore I want to address the duration based on my own data duration data set(skipping duration numbers which don't exist) and match the corresponding price with that duration. As there are many durations with different prices, a histogram seems to be most logical.

So my question, how do I customize these sliders with my own data?